# Getting the email column index when choosing a contact java android

Tags: java, android, android-contentprovider, android-contacts, contactscontract

I am currently selecting a contact from the phones contact book, and then saving the name with the following code:

```
int nameColumn = cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME);
String name = cursor.getString(nameColumn)
```

I am wondering if there is a way to get the email of the contact in a similar fashion, something like `CommonDataKinds.Phone.EMAIL`

Answer (score 0):

> selecting a contact from the phones contact book

by that you mean you're using:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, Contacts.CONTENT_URI);
startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_CONTACT)
```

to have the user pick a contact from the device's contacts app?

If so, you can slightly change the picker code to become an email-picker instead:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, Email.CONTENT_URI);  
startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_EMAIL);
```

Then in your `onActivityResult`:

```
Uri emailUri = data.getData();
Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(emailUri, null, null, null, null);
String email = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Email.DATA)); // get the email itself

DatabaseUtils.dumpCursor(cursor); // dump the cursor so you can see the fields and data you can access
cursor.close();
```